# How to execute window.open(url2) after window.open(url1) is completed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to run

```
let pwa = window.open(url1);
```

which will download a file and only after that, I need to run

```
pwa = window.open(url2);
```

which will also download another file.
How can I utilize pwa to do this? Or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Afaik there's no way to detect a "native" download has finished, at least not client-side. What you can do instead is fetch() the data, then create a Blob and trigger a download for that (`location = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));`). Since the data is already downloaded, the browser download will finish almost instantly. Not sure what PWA or Angular has to do with that though.

Comment: Are both url1 and url2 HTML files, and is each file from the same domain as the parent window?

Comment: @traktor, they are not HTML files, they will return blob, and yes the domains are the same.